# How to use both wifi and cellular network on mobile phone at the same time?

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter, mobile-phone, wan, mobile-broadband

Nowadays, many mobile phones can access network via different channels including cellular network as well as wifi, and for phone with dual sim, they can also access multiple networks. For fastest connection speed, is it possible to control the modem chip within the phones and access all the different available WAN connections at the same time for maximum speed connection?

Comment: You won’t be able to do this both Android and iOS don’t allow this and prioritize WiFi connections for data.  Even if you could do this it wouldn’t make your download speeds any faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhones do this automatically via “Wi-Fi Assist” and Multipath TCP (MPTCP). See the [WWDC 2017 talk from Christoph Paasch](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2017/707h2gkb95cx1l/707/hls_vod_mvp.m3u8#t=19:09) for more information about how apps can make use of MPTCP in iOS 11 and beyond.

Aggregating bandwidth from multiple dissimilar networks with different IP address spaces means you have to either route different flows over different interfaces, or use something like MPTCP up at the transport layer to combine multiple flows into a single TCP stream.

MPTCP is available to be compiled into the Linux kernel (including [Android Linux kernels](https://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/Android)) from the open source project [multipath-tcp.org](https://www.multipath-tcp.org), but it has not been upstreamed into the main kernel sources yet, last time I checked. So you could compile and install your own Android Linux kernels with MPTCP to get this functionality on an Android phone.